# Cart discount for a product category based on quantity calculations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

I wan to add a function to woocommerce that will calculate a 10% discount when 12-23 items from one category is added to the cart.

Then if 24 - 47 items of the category are added it would be a 15% discount.

Last if 48+ items from this category are added it would be a 20% discount.

actual code example would be awesome as I am new to woocommerce

Comment: Have you tried plugins that can do these types of discounts? Maybe https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/pricing-deals-for-woocommerce/

Comment: I have tried a number of plugins with no success. I tried the pricing-deals-for-woocommerce

Comment: @DustySatterlee Just re-updated my answer there was a small error… 2 mistakes in the code… Now is working perfect.

Answer (score 3):

> **Updated** — *Corrected code mistakes and added enhancements in the outputted discount text*

Here is the function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** hook that is going to make the discount for that particular category (or subcategory too) based on cart item quantity calculations.

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'cart_items_quantity_wine_discount', 10, 1 );
function cart_items_quantity_wine_discount($cart_object) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Set HERE your category (can be an ID, a slug or the name)
    $category = 34; // or a slug: $category = 'wine';

    $category_count = 0;
    $category_total = 0;
    $discount = 0;

    // Iterating through each cart item
    foreach($cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item):

        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) ):
            $category_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            $category_total += $cart_item["line_total"]; // calculated total items amount (quantity x price)
        endif;

    endforeach;

    $discount_text = __( 'Quantity discount of ', 'woocommerce' );

    // ## CALCULATIONS ##
    if ( $category_count >= 12 && $category_count < 24 ) {
        $discount -= $category_total * 0.1; // Discount of 10% 
        $discount_text_output = $discount_text . '10%';
    } elseif ( $category_count >= 24 && $category_count < 48 ) {
        $discount -= $category_total * 0.15; // Discount of 15%
        $discount_text_output = $discount_text . '15%';
    } elseif ( $category_count >= 48 ) {
        $discount -= $category_total * 0.2; // Discount of 20%
        $discount_text_output = $discount_text . '20%';
    }

    // Adding the discount
    if ( $discount != 0 && $category_count >= 12 )
        $cart_object->add_fee( $discount_text_output, $discount, false );

    // Note: Last argument in add_fee() method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false)
}
```

> **Note:** Last argument in [**`add_fee()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount…

Code is tested and fully functional.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

---

Other similar: [Discount for Certain Category Based on Total Number of Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871142/woocommerce-discount-for-certain-category-based-on-total-number-of-products/40899247#40899247)