# WooCommerce Cart quantity based discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

In WooCommerce, how do I set a cart discount based on the total number of items in the cart?

For example:

- 1 to 4 items - no discount
- 5 to 10 items - 5%
- 11 to 15 items - 10%
- 16 to 20 items - 15%
- 21 to 25 items - 20%
- 26 to 30 items - 25%

I've search internet but not found any solution or plugins available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a negative cart fee to get a discount. Then you will add your conditions & calculations to a acustom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** action hook, this way:

```
## Tested and works on WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3.0+
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_cart_quantity_discount', 10, 1 );
function wc_cart_quantity_discount( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    ## -------------- DEFINIG VARIABLES ------------- ##
    $discount = 0;
    $cart_item_count = $cart_object->get_cart_contents_count();
    $cart_total_excl_tax = $cart_object->subtotal_ex_tax;

    ## ----------- CONDITIONAL PERCENTAGE ----------- ##
    if( $cart_item_count <= 4 )
        $percent = 0;
    elseif( $cart_item_count >= 5 && $cart_item_count <= 10 )
        $percent = 5;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 10 && $cart_item_count <= 15 )
        $percent = 10;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 15 && $cart_item_count <= 20 )
        $percent = 15;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 20 && $cart_item_count <= 25 )
        $percent = 20;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 25 )
        $percent = 25;


    ## ------------------ CALCULATION ---------------- ##
    $discount -= ($cart_total_excl_tax / 100) * $percent;

    ## ----  APPLYING CALCULATED DISCOUNT TAXABLE ---- ##
    if( $percent > 0 )
        $cart_object->add_fee( __( "Quantity discount $percent%", "woocommerce" ), $discount, true);
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works on WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3.0+

Comment: The above code I need to assign for particular category is possible?

Comment: @Sharvan Yes it's possible… You can see [this related thread too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41027712/3730754)

Comment: the discount we can add in the product detail page instead of cart page?

Comment: @Sharvan No it's a global cart discount…

Comment: @Giuls I've tested it and it's a total discount, How should we manage to set discount only for those extra Items and not on All of them ?