# WooCommerce Cart Quantity Base Discount dispaly also in mini-cart(.php)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

Related to: [WooCommerce Cart Quantity Base Discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856874/woocommerce-cart-quantity-base-discount)

In WooCommerce, how do I set a cart discount based on the total number of items in the cart?

```
## Tested and works on WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3.0+
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_cart_quantity_discount', 10, 1 );
function wc_cart_quantity_discount( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    ## -------------- DEFINIG VARIABLES ------------- ##
    $discount = 0;
    $cart_item_count = $cart_object->get_cart_contents_count();
    $cart_total_excl_tax = $cart_object->subtotal_ex_tax;

    ## ----------- CONDITIONAL PERCENTAGE ----------- ##
    if( $cart_item_count <= 4 )
        $percent = 0;
    elseif( $cart_item_count >= 5 && $cart_item_count <= 10 )
        $percent = 5;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 10 && $cart_item_count <= 15 )
        $percent = 10;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 15 && $cart_item_count <= 20 )
        $percent = 15;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 20 && $cart_item_count <= 25 )
        $percent = 20;
    elseif( $cart_item_count > 25 )
        $percent = 25;


    ## ------------------ CALCULATION ---------------- ##
    $discount -= ($cart_total_excl_tax / 100) * $percent;

    ## ----  APPLYING CALCULATED DISCOUNT TAXABLE ---- ##
    if( $percent > 0 )
        $cart_object->add_fee( __( "Quantity discount $percent%", "woocommerce" ), $discount, true);
}
```

Is good for cart page, it's ok!

QUESTION:

It is possible to integrate this function so that the discounted subtotal is also visible in the **mini-cart**,

as form:

....->add_fee( __( "Quantity discount $percent%", "woocommerce" ), $discount, true);

Thanks in advance.

Dom