# How to apply discount on variable and single products, based on cart quantity and product attribute in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I am trying to apply a percentage discount based on quantity of products with a specific product attribute, in cart.

More precisely my goal is to apply 15% discount on orders of minimum 6 products with the attribute `flaske`.

I have managed to achieve this for variable products with variation attributes set, but I can't seem to target the single/simple products.

My code so far (borrowed from [Condition for Quantity and Price for Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76580613/condition-for-quantity-and-price-for-woocommerce)):

```
// Discount based on product quantity and attribute in cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_cart_item_quantity_discount' );
function wc_cart_item_quantity_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // INITIALIZING VARIABLES
    $min_item_amount = 6; // Min quantity
    $discount = $items_count = $percent = $items_subtotal = 0;
    $taxonomy   = 'pa_variant'; // Taxonomy
    $term_slugs = array('flaske'); // Term/terms
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      // Loop through variation
      foreach( $cart_item['variation'] as $attribute => $term_slug ) {
        // Only counting items that are above 6 and has attribute
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_price() >= $min_item_amount && $attribute === 'attribute_'.$taxonomy && in_array( $term_slug, $term_slugs ) ) {
            $items_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            $items_subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
        }
      }
    }
    // CONDITIONAL PERCENTAGE
    if ($items_count >= 6 ) {
        $percent = 15;
    }
    // DISCOUNT (TAXABLE)
    if( $items_count > 0 ) {
        // Calculation
        $discount -= ($items_subtotal / 100) * $percent;
        $cart->add_fee( __( "Mix & Match rabat - $percent%", "woocommerce" ), $discount, true);
    }
}
```

My current code works very well for variable products (the variants), but it doesn't seem to affect single products, even if I give the single products the same attributes as the variable product.

I suspect it has to do with the `foreach` loop `foreach( $cart_item['variation'] as $attribute => $term_slug )`

How can I make this work in general, so it also applies for single/simple products with same attribute `flaske`?

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

**Other useful references:**

[Woocommerce percentage discount per item based on quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63889760/woocommerce-percentage-discount-per-item-based-on-quantity)

[Exclude variations with 2 specific attribute terms from coupon usage in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297527/exclude-variations-with-2-specific-attribute-terms-from-coupon-usage-in-woocomme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the product attributes set in simple or variable products, in the same way as for product variations.

The following revisited code should also handle simple products (untested):

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_cart_item_quantity_discount' );
function wc_cart_item_quantity_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // INITIALIZING VARIABLES
    $discount = $items_count = $percent = $items_subtotal = 0;
    $taxonomy   = 'pa_variant'; // Taxonomy
    $term_slugs = array('flaske'); // Term/terms
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        // Product variations
        if( $product->is_type('variation') ) {
            // Loop through variation attributes
            foreach ($cart_item['variation'] as $attribute => $term_slug) {
                // Only counting items that are above 6 and has attribute
                if ($attribute === 'attribute_' . $taxonomy && in_array($term_slug, $term_slugs)) {
                    $items_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
                    $items_subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
                }
            }
        } 
        // Simple products
        elseif ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
            $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

            if( ! empty($attributes) && array_key_exists($taxonomy, $attributes) ) {
                $terms = (array) $attributes[$taxonomy]->get_terms(); // array of WP_Term objects
                $slugs = array_map(function($term) { return $term->slug; }, $terms); // Extract only the term slugs

                if (count( array_intersect($slugs, $term_slugs) ) > 0 ) {
                    $items_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
                    $items_subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // CONDITIONAL PERCENTAGE
    if ($items_count >= 6) {
        $percent = 15;
    }
    // DISCOUNT (TAXABLE)
    if ($items_count > 0) {
        // Calculation
        $discount -= ($items_subtotal / 100) * $percent;
        $cart->add_fee(__("Mix & Match rabat - $percent%", "woocommerce"), $discount, true);
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I appriciate your help @LoicTheAztec ! Your code is working as intended, so are your comments. I am curious to why we compare the current active price `$Price` with '$min_item_amount' in `if ($price >= $min_item_amount && count( array_intersect($slugs, $term_slugs) ) > 0 )`.

Comment: Because you were already doing that in your code for the product variations, so I adapted for simple products.

Comment: Ok. That part is totally unnecessary and can be omitted from the code to make it much cleaner. The variable `$min_item_amount = 6;` doesn't make any sense as `$items_count >= 6` is the determinant condition. `$price   = $product->get_price();` and `$price >= $min_item_amount` are unnecessary because product price shouldn't determine my discount condition. Removing this from the code doesn't affect the behavior I am trying to achieve.