# WooCommerce - Conditional Cart calculations based on subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

I have very specific project and I need some different cart rule. I could not find plugin or any other resource about how to achieve this.

I have subcategory 1 (i.e. Tables) and subcategory 2 (i.e. Chairs). Users can only add 1 product from the **subcategory Tables** which is mandatory and as much products as they want from the **subcategory Chairs** which is not-mandatory.

**I need next rule:** If users also added products from the **subcategory Chairs** then subtract total price of the **subcategory Chairs** products from the **subcategory Tables** product. Also in that case if the price will be < 0, then set price to 0.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this using standard Wordpress Woocommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make this work, adding a discount in cart based on your subcategories requirement and calculations…

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','table_chairs_cart_discount', 10, 1 );
function table_chairs_cart_discount($cart_object) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Initializing variables
    $chairs_total = 0;
    $table_total = 0;
    $discount = 0;

    // Iterating through each cart item
    foreach($cart_object->get_cart() as $item_key => $item):

        $item_line_total = $item["line_total"]; // Item total price (price x quantity)

        // Chairs subcategory items
        if(has_term('chairs', 'product_cat', $item['product_id']))
            $chairs_total += $item_line_total;

        // Table subcategory items
        if(has_term('table', 'product_cat', $item['product_id']))
            $table_total += $item_line_total;

    endforeach;

    // ## CALCULATIONS ##
    if( $table_total <= $chairs_total && $chairs_total > 0 ) 
        $discount -= $table_total;
    elseif ($chairs_total > 0) 
        $discount -= $chairs_total;

    // Adding the discount
    if ($discount != 0)
        $cart_object->add_fee( __( 'Chairs discount', 'woocommerce' ), $discount, false );
        // Note: Last argument in add_fee() method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false)
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.

---

Related answer: [Discount for Certain Category Based on Total Number of Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871142/woocommerce-discount-for-certain-category-based-on-total-number-of-products/40899247#40899247)