# Adding a discount by cart items conditionally based on the item quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I have set up a Woocommerce shop and wish to set up a specific discount on all products based on multiples of 12 (a box). I've tried many discount plugins but haven't found what I am looking for.

For example, if I order 12 of product X, I get a 10% discount. If I order 15 of product X, I get a 10% discount on the first 12, and the last three are full price. If I order 24, then that 10% discount applies to all 24 of product X.

The closest I have found is this: [Discount for Certain Category Based on Total Number of Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871142/discount-for-certain-category-based-on-total-number-of-products/40899247#40899247)

But this is applied as a discount (actually a negative fee) at the end, and I'd like to display the discount in the cart next to the product, like normal discounts.

**I also need this discount to be disabled if a product is already on sale.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **This code will not work in Woocommerce 3+**…
>
> See: [Cart item discount based on quantity in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010505/cart-item-discount-based-on-quantity-in-woocommerce-3/52012795#52012795):

Yes this is also possible, making a custom calculation for each cart item and replacing individually their price *(matching your conditions and calculations)*, using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`** action hook.

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_discounted_cart_item_price', 10, 1 );
function custom_discounted_cart_item_price( $cart_object ) {

    $discount_applied = false;

    // Set Here your targeted quantity discount
    $t_qty = 12;

    // Iterating through each item in cart
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {

        ##  Get cart item data
        $item_id = $item_values['data']->id; // Product ID
        $item_qty = $item_values['quantity']; // Item quantity
        $original_price = $item_values['data']->price; // Product original price

        // Getting the object
        $product = new WC_Product( $item_id );


        // CALCULATION FOR EACH ITEM 
        // when quantity is up to the targetted quantity and product is not on sale
        if( $item_qty >= $t_qty && !$product->is_on_sale() ){
            for($j = $t_qty, $loops = 0; $j <= $item_qty; $j += $t_qty, $loops++);

            $modulo_qty = $item_qty % $t_qty; // The remaining non discounted items

            $item_discounted_price = $original_price * 0.9; // Discount of 10 percent

            $total_discounted_items_price = $loops * $t_qty * $item_discounted_price;

            $total_normal_items_price = $modulo_qty * $original_price;

            // Calculating the new item price
            $new_item_price = ($total_discounted_items_price + $total_normal_items_price) / $item_qty;


            // Setting the new price item
            $item_values['data']->price = $new_item_price;

            $discount_applied = true;
        }
    }
    // Optionally display a message for that discount
    if ( $discount_applied )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'A quantity discount has been applied on some cart items.', 'my_theme_slug' ), 'success' );
}
```

> This make exactly the discount that you are expecting separately for each item in cart (based on it's quantity) **and not for items that are in sale**. But you will not get any label (text) indicating a discount in the line items of cart.
>
> Optionally I display a notice when a discount is applied to some cart items…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect.