# Cart item quantity progressive percentage discount in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I am trying to apply a TOTAL CART discount to all the items in the cart, depending on the quantity of items added. I have taken and modified the code example from [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010505/cart-item-discount-based-on-quantity-in-woocommerce-3/52012795#52012795) and got most of the logic working.

I cannot however get it working for two scenarios described below. It also only applies the rule to a single item in the cart. Not the entire cart.

**Scenario:**

- If no of items in the cart are between 9-12, Apply 5% Discount to all items.
- If no of items in the cart are between 13-16, Apply 10% Discount to all items.
- The discount's should not stack. e.g. when 12 items in cart, apply 5% discount...when 13 items added, remove 5% discount and apply 10% discount.

**Code:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_items_default_price_as_custom_data', 20, 3 );
function add_items_default_price_as_custom_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    ## ----- YOUR SETTING ----- ##
    $discount_percentage = 5; // Discount (5%)

    // The WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    // Only for non on sale products
    if( ! $product->is_on_sale() ){
        $price = (float) $product->get_price();

        // Set the Product default base price as custom cart item data
        $cart_item_data['base_price'] = $price;

        // Set the Product discounted price as custom cart item data
        $cart_item_data['new_price'] = $price * (100 - $discount_percentage) / 100;

        // Set the percentage as custom cart item data
        $cart_item_data['percentage'] = $discount_percentage;
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display the product original price
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_default_price', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_default_price( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset($cart_item['base_price']) ) {
        $product        = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $cart_item['base_price'] ) ) );
    }
    return $product_price;
}

// Display the product name with the discount percentage
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'append_percetage_to_item_name', 20, 3 );
function append_percetage_to_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset($cart_item['percentage']) && isset($cart_item['base_price']) ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_price() != $cart_item['base_price'] )
            $product_name .= ' <em>(' . $cart_item['percentage'] . '% discounted)</em>';
    }
    return $product_name;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_discounted_cart_item_price', 20, 1 );
function custom_discounted_cart_item_price( $cart ) {

    ## ----- YOUR SETTING ----- ##
    $balanced_qty = 9; // Targeted quantity
    $upper_balanced_qty = 12; // Max quantity limit
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // For item quantity between 9 and 12
        if( ($cart_item['quantity'] >= $balanced_qty && isset($cart_item['new_price']) && ($cart_item['quantity'] <= $upper_balanced_qty) ) ){

            // Set cart item discounted price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['new_price']);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the discount based on item quantity or on global items count?

Comment: I think what you mean by `global items count` is the whole cart count? if so, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by cart item quantity or globally based on cart items count:

**1) By cart item quantity:**

```
// Utility function that give the discount percentage based on quantity argument
function get_discount_percent( $quantity ){
    if( $quantity < 9 )
        $percent = 0;  // 0 %  ( quantity from 1 to 8 )
    elseif( $quantity >= 9 && $quantity < 13 )
        $percent = 5;  // 5 %  ( quantity from 9 to 12 )
    else
        $percent = 10; // 10 % ( quantity up to 13 )

    return $percent;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_items_default_price_as_custom_data', 20, 3 );
function add_items_default_price_as_custom_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    ## ----- YOUR SETTING ----- ##
    $percent_1 = 5; //  Discount (5%)
    $percent_2 = 10; // Discount (10%)

    // The WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    $price = (float) $product->get_price();

    // Set the Product default base price as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discount'][0] = $price;

    // Set the Product discounted price of 5% as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discount'][$percent_1] = $price * (100 - $percent_1) / 100;

    // Set the Product discounted price of 10% as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discount'][$percent_2] = $price * (100 - $percent_2) / 100;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display the product original price
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_default_price', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_default_price( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset($cart_item['discount'][0]) ) {
        $product        = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $cart_item['discount'][0] ) ) );
    }
    return $product_price;
}

// Display the product name with the discount percentage
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'append_percetage_to_item_name', 20, 3 );
function append_percetage_to_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    // get the percent based on quantity
    $percent = get_discount_percent($cart_item['quantity']);

    if( isset($cart_item['discount'][$percent]) && isset($cart_item['discount'][0]) ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_price() != $cart_item['discount'][0] )
            $product_name .= ' <em>(' . $percent . '% discounted)</em>';
    }
    return $product_name;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_discount_cart_item_price', 25, 1 );
function set_custom_discount_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // get the percent based on quantity
        $percentage = get_discount_percent($cart_item['quantity']);
        
        // For items non on sale set a discount based on quantity as defined in
        if( $percentage != 0 && isset($cart_item['discount'][$percentage]) && ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['discount'][$percentage]);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**2) Globally on cart item count** *(for non on sale products)*:

```
// Utility function that give the discount percentage based on quantity argument
function get_discount_percent( $quantity ){
    if( $quantity < 9 )
        $percent = 0;  // 0 %  ( quantity from 1 to 8 )
    elseif( $quantity >= 9 && $quantity < 13 )
        $percent = 5;  // 5 %  ( quantity from 9 to 12 )
    else
        $percent = 10; // 10 % ( quantity up to 13 )

    return $percent;
}

// Utility function that count cart items that are not on sale
function get_non_on_sale_cart_items_count(){
    $items_count = 0;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ){
            $items_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    return $items_count;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_items_default_price_as_custom_data', 20, 3 );
function add_items_default_price_as_custom_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    ## ----- YOUR SETTING ----- ##
    $percent_1 = 5; //  Discount (5%)
    $percent_2 = 10; // Discount (10%)

    // The WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    $price = (float) $product->get_price();

    // Set the Product default base price as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discount'][0] = $price;

    // Set the Product discounted price of 5% as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discount'][$percent_1] = $price * (100 - $percent_1) / 100;

    // Set the Product discounted price of 10% as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discount'][$percent_2] = $price * (100 - $percent_2) / 100;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display the product original price
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_default_price', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_default_price( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset($cart_item['discount'][0]) ) {
        $product        = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $cart_item['discount'][0] ) ) );
    }
    return $product_price;
}

// Display the product name with the discount percentage
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'append_percetage_to_item_name', 20, 3 );
function append_percetage_to_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    // Get cart items count
    $items_count = get_non_on_sale_cart_items_count();

    // get the percent based on quantity
    $percent = get_discount_percent($items_count);

    if( isset($cart_item['discount'][$percent]) && isset($cart_item['discount'][0]) ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_price() != $cart_item['discount'][0] )
            $product_name .= ' <em>(' . $percent . '% discounted)</em>';
        elseif ( $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() && $percent != 0 ){
            $product_name .= ' <em>(Item on sale)</em>';
        }
    }
    return $product_name;
}

// Change cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_discount_cart_item_price', 25, 1 );
function set_custom_discount_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Get cart items count
    $items_count = get_non_on_sale_cart_items_count();

    // get the percent based on quantity
    $percentage = get_discount_percent($items_count);

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // For items non on sale set a discount based on quantity as defined in
        if( $percentage != 0 && isset($cart_item['discount'][$percentage]) && ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['discount'][$percentage]);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Here below, in this example, the third item is on sale, so the real count is `10 + 1 = 11` items and then the discount for **`11`** items is **`5%`**:
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, this is helpful, however it doesn't apply the discount to the entire cart...it does it on a per item basis. Can it be modified to apply discount based on the total amount of items in the cart?

Comment: @Giuls You should try to be more clear when you ask a question please. I am going to make an addition update after this answer code.

Comment: Okay thanks, my apologies if I was unclear or confusion in the original question.

Comment: @Giuls Ok I have updated the answer, with a 2nd version code that should match your requirement.

Comment: Thanks very much! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a discount to the whole cart by apply a negative fee.

See: [Apply a discount on the cart content total excluding taxes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802738/apply-a-discount-on-the-cart-content-total-excluding-taxes-in-woocommerce)

Try the code below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_discounted_cart_item_price', 20, 1 );
function custom_discounted_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
  $total_cart_items_count = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
  $discount = null;

  // Apply 5% discount between 9 - 12 items
  if( $total_cart_items_count >= 9 && $total_cart_items_count <= 12 ) {
    // Calculate 5% of cart total
    $discount = $cart->get_cart_contents_total() * 5 / 100;
  }

  // Apply 10% discount between 13 - 16 items
  if( $total_cart_items_count >= 13 && $total_cart_items_count <= 16 ) {
    // Calculate 10% of cart total
    $discount = $cart->get_cart_contents_total() * 10 / 100;
  }

  if( !empty( $discount ) ) {
    $cart->add_fee(
      __( 'Discount', 'woocommerce' ) . '($percent%)',
      -$discount,
      false // TAX
    );
  }
}
```